# Linux Threads and process - CPU affinity

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, pthreads

I have few queries related to threads and Process scheduling.

1. When my process goes into sleep and wakes back, is it always that it will be scheduled on the same CPU that it got scheduled before?
2. When i create a thread from the process, Will it also be executed on the same CPU always? Even if other CPU's are free and sleeping.

I would like to know the mechanism in Linux in specific. Also i am creating the threads through pthread library. I am facing a random hangup issue which is always not reproducible. Need this information to proceed in the right direction.

Comment: You can mostly assume "We cannot know/We cannot tell/We cannot predict" for these kind of questions as the reply. It is almost impossibe to answer these with precision AFAIK because parameters involved in this kind of decision making are very huge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On single processor/core systems

1. Yes
2. Yes

on multi processor/core systems

1. No.
2. No.

use [taskset](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/taskset1.html) to retrieve or set a processes’s CPU affinity on multicore systems. Setting the CPU affinity to **a specific** processor/core will change the answers to

1. Yes
2. Yes

also for multicore systems.

From within an application you may use [sched_setaffinity and/or sched_getaffinity](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/man/sched_setaffinity.txt) to adjust the CPU affinity.

---

**Edit:** Additional details about how/when CPU swaps are managed with respect to cache disadvantages:

[The Linux/SMP Scheduler](http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html):  *"... In order to achieve good system performance, Linux/SMP (2.4 kernel) adopts an empirical rule to solve the dilemma ..."* Read the details in the linked reference, section **The Linux/SMP Scheduler**.

For the newer CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) you'd look at `sched_migration_cost`. *"...if the real runtime of the task is smaller than the values of this parameter then the scheduler assumes that it is still in the cache and tries to avoid moving the task to another CPU during the load balancing procedure ..."* (e.g.: [Completely Fair Scheduler and its tuning](http://www.fizyka.umk.pl/~jkob/prace-mag/cfs-tuning.pdf)).

Comment: Hi @Arno This is whate exactly i was also thinking. But i read in some source which i cannot recollect where, that Because the pages will be loaded into L1 and L2 caches before executing, generally(that is mostly) a process will be rescheduled on the same CPU(to avoid page faults). Any idea about this? So what is the  probability of the same CPU being chosen? Is it same as any other CPU or is it more probable that it would be rescheduled on the same CPU that of before? The issue is solved however I would like to know these details as they would help in debugging.

Comment: @Manty: A process will be rescheduled to the processor on which it was running on, when 
the processor becomes available for this process (no other processes are ahead
in scheduling for this processor). When the processor is not available due to other
processes but the process heads the scheduling queue for another processor, it will
continue on another processor. You're asking for a "soft affinity" which shall
prefer processes on a specific processor based on the fact that they have been 
running on that processor before. Such a "soft affinity" does not exist.

Comment: with no disrespect, may I ask you the source of this information if you have something? Code or books.. anything that draws the above inference would do

Comment: @Manty: [The Linux/SMP Scheduler](http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html): _... In order to achieve good system performance, Linux/SMP adopts an empirical rule to solve the dilemma ..._ Read the details in the linked reference, section **The Linux/SMP Scheduler**.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have one query. It shows the details wrt 2.4 Kernel. I think currently Linux is using CFS which is differrent from the one explained here. Probably only browsing through source code of latest kernel would help like you did for your proj.

Comment: For the newer **CFS** you'd look at **sched_migration_cost**. _...if the real runtime of the task is smaller than the values of this parameter then the scheduler assumes that it is still in the cache and tries to avoid moving the task to another CPU during the load balancing procedure ..._ (e.g.: [Completely Fair Scheduler and its tuning](http://www.fizyka.umk.pl/~jkob/prace-mag/cfs-tuning.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks @Arno. I Really appreciate your efforts. Just in case, would you like to change the answer according to our discussion before i accept?

Answer (score 0):

when process goes in to sleep and when it wake up ,it is not necessary that it will schedule on same cpu.if u have multiprocessor environment then according to scheduler policy it will schedule on any cpu.When process goes to sleep there are different reason ,it goes to sleep beacause it is waiting for io,any resource.When event will occurs it goes from waiting state to ready state.At that time which cpu will be free scheduler will schedule that process on free cpu.It is not necessary it will schedule on same cpu.
         for extra information about scheduler open source code of scheduler in linux release tree path.